# parsing images with lazy load

Tags: javascript

I need some help with fixing parsing images with lazy load. I got just code scraped to my website instead of pictures itself.

I put data-srcset at the source attribute field, but it does not change anything.

And i tried to use data-src, data-original and just src as well.

```html
<figure class="item-img"><div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:1000px;"><div class="responsive-img img-article-item" style="padding-bottom: 50%">
<picture><!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
<source media="(min-width: 1024px)" sizes="740px" data-srcset="https://***.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ff7-ch14-41.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=740&amp;h=370&amp;dpr=1.5 740w">
<source media="(min-width: 768px)" sizes="963px" data-srcset="https://***.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ff7-ch14-41.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=963&amp;h=481&amp;dpr=1.5 963w">
<source media="(min-width: 481px)" sizes="737px" data-srcset="https://****/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ff7-ch14-41.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=737&amp;h=368&amp;dpr=1.5 737w">
<source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="450px" data-srcset="https://***.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ff7-ch14-41.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=450&amp;h=225&amp;dpr=1.5 450w">
<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]--><img class="lazyload" alt="В*****"></picture></div></div>
</figure><div class="ad-even">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that most lazy-loading solutions for the web work involve javascript that listens for an event that tells it to 'activate' the source tag by entering a value into the src or srcset attributes. data-src and data-srcset are how these JS systems store the url of the resource they are lazy-loading without tipping off the  tag to actually load them. When the time comes for the image to be displayed, the JS moves the data-src tag content into the src attribute and the image is then loaded. I'm assuming the code you copied this from had such a function configured.

As a consequence of this, if you just have  tags without a JS function watching over them ready to switch them on when the time comes, then they'll never load the resource you're looking for. Your browser doesn't know what data-src or data-srcset means and won't read those values. You'll have to configure a lazy-loading function or write one yourself to get this to work.